# to much usage RAM for application

Tags: java, android, performance, cpu, ram

I would like to reduce memory consumption. My application is small and consumes between 20-45 mb of RAM. The problem arises when I add a lot of new things and objects means that soon we get error out of bounds.

I have got situation like that:

- 2 arrays of special object for save all object, lines, rectengls etc..
- 2 arrays of strings same lenght of 2 arrey like special object)
- 3 bitmaps lenght (500*500-1500*1500px)samtink like that costum pictures.
  -1 array of byts for loading pictures
- and other 60-70 special types of ints,floats,strings,boleans..

How can i change and try to make smaller usage for ram. i think it is urgently now. I need suggestions for profesional programers :) How can i free a memory for variables wich i dont need anymore, and how can i delete button,image button and other thinks from ram

thanks for all suggestion,

lp
piki12

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: java.lang.outofmemoryerror like this, but this is only my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start with RAM reduction are bitmaps as they inherently use a lot of RAM. Instead of loading a full bitmap into memory, it is much more efficient to only load the bitmap at a resolution to match the screen. I recommend you look at: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader which makes this very easy to do.

**EDIT:**
As the question ends up to be using Canvas, this option is not available. Instead you have to implement this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html. It's still not that difficult as the majority of the code is provided.

Comment: yes but i make application for drawing is it posible wor me ?

Comment: It depends what are you using to display the bitmaps ImageView or canvas?

Comment: canvas :)what is better

Comment: @Papi Just different ways of displaying images, unfortunately you don't get to use that library, but there is a tutorial. See my edit