# load picture on change orientation

Tags: java, android

Hy everyone i have got some problems, i make loading system, like that (RSenApps get me some advace and good links)
[to much usage RAM for application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081988/to-much-usage-ram-for-application)

But main problem is if i change orientation there is problem, but i dont know why?

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
  //  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    String imageType = options.outMimeType;
        loadedBmp=decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(mPicturePath, imageWidth, imageHeight);
       public static int calculateInSampleSize( BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;


        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String mpath,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mpath, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mpath, options);
    }
```

Check text there!
[image]
Check text there!
[image]

If anyone have got suggestion pleas help me?

Comment: I want in all orientation full (smaller canvas) picture, and not in one orientation screens

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your manifest file

```
<activity
             android:name="Your Activity Name"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```